# Chartist.js remove labels?

Tags: javascript, html, css, chartist.js

So I can `display:none` the labels ex. below with css, but my .ct-chart still has something on the left and bottom side of the chart ex. image below.

```
.ct-labels, .ct-grids {
  display: none;
}
```

Ideally the blue chart is over to the left of the white module and down on the bottom, so that it matches with the div, it is positioned absolute, and the chart responsiveness is on. I am assuming the white space is created from the labels still existing in the DOM?

[image]

I would like to have the chart showing no white space on the left and bottom side. My `.ct-chart` css looks like this.

```
.ct-chart {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 29):

If you don't want to have labels at all, no grid lines and remove all offsets and padding you can do so but it requires quite a bit of configuration:

```
var chart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
  labels: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  series: [
    [1, 4, 2, 5],
    [2, 3, 1, 4]
  ]
}, {
  showPoint: false,
  showLine: false,
  showArea: true,
  fullWidth: true,
  showLabel: false,
  axisX: {
    showGrid: false,
    showLabel: false,
    offset: 0
  },
  axisY: {
    showGrid: false,
    showLabel: false,
    offset: 0
  },
  chartPadding: 0,
  low: 0
});
```

http://jsbin.com/patela/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: FYI, the full list of options https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/api-documentation.html#chartistline-declaration-defaultoptions

Comment: @DaleZak It guess owner of the answer is also the writer of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those are svg elements with x and y value offsets. See in the example here http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html the elements in 
    < g class="ct-labels">< /g> 
all have an x and y offset defined that move them away from the parent element. It would be pretty simple to override these values with d3 after the chart has loaded.

Comment: Oh okay, I don't know much about svg, I am trying to follow the docs, and it does make it easy but without much svg knowledge its tough, this definitely helps. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

When I load the chart I like to check the chart width and the number of labels and if need be I either display the labels, only display every other label, or hide all the labels based on whether the labels fit.  This code hides the labels:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.ct-chart').find('.ct-labels .ct-horizontal').remove();
}, 100);
```